# Does Room's OnConflict.replace also works if Unique constraint fails?

Tags: android, android-room

So, i have a room database where apart from the Primary key i have a unique indexed column too !

what i want is, IF -> the unique constraint fails - replace the old row with new row ( changing the PRIMARY KEY too ), will `OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE` help ?

or should i delete the previous data upon insert fail and add the new one ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> When a UNIQUE or PRIMARY KEY constraint violation occurs, the REPLACE algorithm deletes pre-existing rows that are causing the constraint violation prior to inserting or updating the current row and the command continues executing normally.

https://sqlite.org/lang_conflict.html

So if the UNIQUE constraint fails then what you want occurs; the following demonstrates this :-

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS test;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, col1 INTEGER, col2 INTEGER, col3 INTEGER DEFAULT (strftime('%s-%f','now')));
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS idx_test_col1_col2 ON test (col1,col2);

INSERT INTO test (col1,col2) VALUES (1,1),(1,2),(2,1),(2,2);
SELECT * FROM test;
INSERT OR REPLACE INTO TEST (col1,col2) VALUES (2,1);
SELECT * FROM test;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS test; -- Cleanup
```

Which results in :-

[image]

- before the unique constraint

and then :-

[image]

- after the unique conflict.

Here's a more comprehensive test that demonstrates other permutations (note the last)

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS test;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, col1 INTEGER, col2 INTEGER, col3 INTEGER DEFAULT (strftime('%s-%f','now')));
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS idx_test_col1_col2 ON test (col1,col2);
INSERT INTO test VALUES (0,0,0,strftime('%s-%f','now'));
INSERT INTO test (col1,col2) VALUES (1,1),(1,2),(2,1),(2,2);
SELECT * FROM test; /* RESULT 1 INITIAL VALUES */
INSERT OR REPLACE INTO test (col1,col2) VALUES (2,1);
SELECT * FROM test; /* RESULT 2 UNIQUE conflict */
INSERT OR REPLACE INTO test (id,col1,col2) VALUES (1,7,7);
SELECT * FROM test; /* RESULT 3 PRIMARY KEY conflict */
INSERT OR REPLACE INTO test (id,col1,col2) VALUES (2,1,2);
SELECT * FROM test; /* RESULT 4 BOTH PRIMARY KEY and UNIQUE conflict on the same row (see timing) */
INSERT OR REPLACE INTO test (id,col1,col2) VALUES (4,7,7);
SELECT * FROM test; /* RESULTS 5 BOTH conflict BUT conflicts are for different rows */
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS test; -- Cleanup
```

This results in:-

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

- So with the last INSERT 2 rows were deleted. Row with id 4 due to the PRIMARY KEY conflict and also row with id 1 due to the UNIQUE conflict and 1 row (4,7,7) has been added.

Comment: Nice ! Thanksss a lotttt  for the detailed explanation

Comment: @Divesh if you found the answer helpful then please tick the answer to indicate this (perhaps also do this with other answers you have been provided with if they too helped).

Comment: didn't know about that - did now ! will do with others too , thanks again